# Hadoop map-reduce programming

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in Hadoop Map-reduce. My input is many text files and I want to write the map-reduce program such that it will write all the files-names and the associated sentences with the file names in one output file where
I want to just emit the file-name(key) and the associated sentences(value) from the mapper and the reducer will collect the key and all the values and write the file-name and their associated sentences in the output.

*Mapper and reducer:*

```java
public void map(Text key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");
    String filename = new String();
    FileSplit filesplit = (FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit();
    filename = filesplit.getpath().getName();
    while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        output.collect(new Text(filename), word);
    }
}

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                   OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                   Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    // int sum = 0;
    String translation = "";
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        translation += "|" + values.toString() + "|";
    }

    results.set(translation);
    output.collect(key, results);
}
```

When I run the above mapper and reducer with the same configuration of inputformat (keyvaluetextinputformat.class) it does not write any thing in the output.

What should I change to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reduce method you declare values to be an Iterator.  It should be declared as an Iterable instead.

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, ....
```

instead of

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, ....
```

Once you've done that, you can do:

```
Iterator<Text> iter = values.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    translation += "|" + iter.next().toString() + "|";
}
```

Because you used the wrong type the method isn't overriding the default reduce method which doesn't do anything.  That's why you get no output.

I also don't see where you declare the variable results, either.

Comment: no sir, not working still i get the blank output,, is it translation+= "|" + values.toString() + "|"; or translation+= "|" + iter.toString() + "|";

Comment: What is variable results?  I did not see where it was declared.  Are you running this locally or remotely?  How many files do you have?

Comment: But sir when I change iterator to iterable it first gives a error saying "Reduce must implement the inherited abstract method Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>.reduce(Text,Iterator<Text>,OutputCollector<Text,Text"

Comment: Sir I have declared the variable results in the Reduce Class, "private Text results = new Text();" I have only one file Sample.txt as only one input file...

Comment: Sir, But what I will do with  error saying "Reduce must implement the inherited abstract method Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>.reduce(Text,Iterator<Text>,OutputCollector<Text,Tex‌​t

Comment: For the error message, add an @override annotation to the method.  If it still fails then edit your question with the full source.  Another debugging technique is to use hadoop counters to count the number of times you run through a section of code.

Comment: One more thing... update your question to show the job counters report.  That will show number of records read and written by the mapper and reducer and helps to see where data stopped flowing